# Deploy hippo cms in heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, hippocms

In Hippo, There are two web applications packaged as war files inside a directory called webapps, a number of libraries in a directory called shared/lib, another set in a directory called common/lib, and some configuration files such as a log4j descriptor and a Tomcat context descriptor in the conf directory.

But in Heroku, I can not find the directory of tomcat to deploy these directory like the structure of Hippo (shared/lib, common/lib, conf)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hippo requires access to the entire Tomcat instance for setup at least. I've read through the Heroku documentation (most of it just skimmed), but I can't see that they provide that access.

However, there is possibly a second option which you may be willing to try; build Hippo in a docker image, and deploy that into Heroku:

[Creating a docker container for hippo](https://www.onehippo.org/labs/creating-a-docker-container-for-hippo-cms.html)

[Deploying docker container to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)

I haven't tried or tested any of this, so I can't guarantee it's success. But if you're limited to using Heroku, then it's at least worth a try.

Also, if you manage to get it running using docker, I would be extremely interested to know more details.